# how to write the regex not to allow spaces in the beginning and ending ,but spaces inneed to allow between the words

Tags: javascript

How can we allow the special characters just like other characters at the same time should not allow the spaces in beginning and ending

```
 public addressPattern: string="[a-zA-Z0-9][\\sa-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}";
```

Comment: @ CBroe, the code which is using now not allowing the special characters .

Comment: @CBroe, ohh  particularly #,.-/ these special characters

Comment: Still didnt get the solution , can anyone provide a solution for this, need a regex code to restrict the space in the begining and ending , but allow in the middle of the characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used so many regex things finally this code help me to solve the issue

```
public addressPattern=/^(?:\S.{0,}\S)?$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression

```
^\S(?:.*\S)?$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `\S` - Match any non space character
- `(?:.*\S)?` - Match anything zero or more time followed non space character (optional)
- `$` - End of string

```js
let checker = (str) => {
  return /^\S(?:.*\S)?$/.test(str)
}

console.log(checker('H'))
console.log(checker(' H'))
console.log(checker('H '))
console.log(checker('Hello friend'))
```

If you want empty string to evaluate true then you can just add one simple condition

```
return str.length === 0 ? true :/^\S(?:.*\S)?$/.test(str)
```

Comment: @you're not allowing any special character in your pattern and also not checking for space at end

Comment: @ Code Maniac ,can you pls tell me how can we check the space at end and also allow special characters  in my code,because whatever you posted i also used that but it showing the validation error .

Comment: @ajay what error it is showing, you need to be specific and detailed about your queries. also you can replace `\S` with character class i.e `[a-zA-Z-0-9#\/@!-]` (whatever characters you want to allow) same with `.` (You can replace this as well with character class )

Comment: @ code maniac im writing the validation message if the user is giving space in the begining and ending .so whenver user giving space in the ending and begining the validation message occurs.but i need to allow other characters including special characters. so im looking for the correct regex code where it match my requirement, (Im not familiar with the regex ).